# Define version or other properties in an .Sql file

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I just want to know that can we define properties in an .sql file or not. The reason that why i want to define a property in the .sql file is for managing version of the database.

For example:
I am using HSQL Database. Currently there are two tables. 
Table 1: Products.
Table 2: version. (it contains just an integer number).

Now what i want is that when my program runs, it checks if version has been changed/upgraded so it can drop the existing db, and upgrade the database according to the new schema and index statements written in an .sql file.

But the issue i am facing is that at the startup of the program , i can read the existing version from the version table, but against which version value i would compare it. 
Because all that would be written in the .sql file would be.

```
Create table products (...);
Create table version (...);
Insert into products values (...);
Insert into version values(2,9-19-2015); //the upgraded version.
```

So either i should parse the version statement written in the end  of the sql file to extract the version number and compare it with the existing version to check if version has been changed or how else can i do it?

So i thought that may be somehow i can define a property in .sql file. Like this.

```
version = 2
Create table products (...);
Create table version (...);
Insert into products values (...);
Insert into version values(2,9-19-2015); //the upgraded version.
```

and then first read the version and compare it. If it is upgraded then run the rest of sql queries.

I mean, is this a good approach to manage version in an database using java. Or how else can i do it?

Many Thanks.

Comment: I have a file for version 1, for version 2, for version 3, for version 4.  Each file bumps the version #.   the way my app runs is if version =1 run script 2.   Then if version = 2 then run script 3.  And so on and so forth.  already updated programs skip all the updates...lower versioned programs end up running each update.

Comment: Rather than re-inventing the wheel, check out e.g. Liquibase or Flyway.